# I can't control my DC motors speed with analogWrite()

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, pwm, analogwrite

I have Arduino Uno and I attached it to 2 DC motors with L298N bridge. 
I want to control the speed of the motors so they don't move at maximum speed. 
I use `analogWrite()` but it does nothing,and the motors move at maximum speed

Here is my code:

```cpp
//motor A
int enA = 9;
int in1 = 8;
int in2 = 7;

//motor B
int enB = 3;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  analogWrite(enA, 0);

  analogWrite(enB, 0);

  digitalWrite (in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (in3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite (in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite (in4, LOW);

  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: Do you know that `analogWrite(enA, 0);` stops it? Or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: With using analogWrite Do make sure you use the pwn pins of arduino to control the motors.

Comment: yes i know that analogWrite(enA,0) stops the motor and that is what i want but it dosen't work and the motors are alwayes at maximum speed

Comment: Please add a schematic of photo of your wiring setup. As you have described it thus far, your code should halt the motor, so perhaps the wiring is not correct.

Comment: @josecanuc i did my wire base on video on youtube with my same electronics and it runs perfect with his device

Comment: @MukharJain i am sure that i am using them and i tried all the pins ,however the problem still the same

Comment: If the youtube video project runs perfect and yours doesn't, this is why we are asking to see what you have done, because of the possibility that you made a mistake in re-creating this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did find solutions for the problem. It turned out that the bridge does not work as it should be and the pins of en(A,B) is replaced with the in pins ..now I can control the speed but can't reverse the direction of the motors

Comment: This was really frustrating to figure out, so thanks for your answer here! I had a similar bad module, and looks like just connecting my pwm pin to IN1 was all that was needed for speed control in a single direction. I just disconnected the enable jumper/pin and in2 pin, and measured a good pwm output. Seems like the enable pin does nothing on my module!

Answer (score 1):

analogWrite() can take values between **0** and **255** as its second parameter. Where 255 will give you the maximum motor speed and 0 will give you the lowest (motor will not run).

For example, below code will give you almost the half of max speed.

```
analogWrite(enA, 128);  
analogWrite(enB, 128);
```

Comment: i know what it does but it does not work the way it should and the motors are allwayes at maximum speed even if i put it to (0) and i am sure of the pins

Comment: I'm looking at one of the L298N bridges on Amazon. What are those two jumpers on pins ENA and ENB? Try taking those off, because I wonder if they're pegging you at full "on".

Comment: @LegitimateWorkUser these are the speed control pins(voltage) if you take them off the motor will not run at all